# Need help fixing "property value expected" in CSS (Beginner/amateur)

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to set up some animated text in my project, but I keep getting an error in vscode saying "property value expected css(css-propertyvalueexpected) [59, 1]" in ".main-title" which I think is leading the code not to work cause it's not showing anything like what I'm trying to do when I open the page in browser, it shows it like the css code is non existent

I haven't tried to fix it, I posted the full code below cause I'm not sure what's causing it and I'm a beginner

```html
<main role="main" class="main-content" id="main-content">
    <div class="titleCont">
        <h1 class="main-title" id="main-title">
            "Here, in the forest,<br><span style="padding-left:100px">dark and deep,</span><br><span style="padding-right:110px">I offer you,</span><br><span style="padding-left:-20px">eternal sleep."</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <canvas id="noise" class="noise"></canvas>
  <div class="vignette"></div>
</main>
```

```css
.main-content {
  overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: column;

    height: 100vh;

    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(36,31,31,1) 0%, rgba(36,31,31,1) 32%, rgba(74,71,70,1) 100%);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.vignette{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 150px 20px black;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  -webkit-animation: vignette-anim 3s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    vignette-anim 3s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      vignette-anim 3s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         vignette-anim 3s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}

.noise {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: .15;
}

.line{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%; width:1px;
  opacity:0.1;
  background-color:#000;
}

.titleCont{position:relative;}

.main-title {
    padding: .3em 1em .25em;    
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
    position:relative;
    line-height:1.3;
    white-spacing:
}

.overTitle{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.dot{
  width:3px;
  height:2px;
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0.3;
}


@-webkit-keyframes vignette-anim {
  0%   , 100%{ opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0.7; }
}
@-moz-keyframes vignette-anim {
  0%   , 100%{ opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0.7; }
}
@-o-keyframes vignette-anim {
  0%   , 100%{ opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0.7; }
}
@keyframes vignette-anim {
  0%   , 100%{ opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0.7; }
}
```

I copy pasted the code from here "https://codepen.io/mimikos/pen/QMjjzy" expected it to look the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `white-spacing:` has no value

Comment: ... and it's misspelled. Should be `white-space`.

Comment: @sleepydev What ARE you actually trying to achieve? What does happen instead? We cannot guess you intentions!

Comment: @yunzen I posted a codepen on the thread for how I want it to be: https://codepen.io/mimikos/pen/QMjjzy

Comment: @sleepydevm In codepen, if you click on settings and go to javascript code, you will see 3 scripts are added, please add them and it will work for you too

Comment: @Sonia Thank you, fixed everything I wanted I just didn't know how to use codepen I guess cause when I saw that everything in js tab was commented thought it was just some random notes. Appreciate it!

Comment: The VScode error has nothing to do with it! It's just an error your linter shows (CSSLint perhaps or Stylelint). The linter is just a _hint_ in the direction for cleaner code. It encourages you to stick to certain rules of code style which will help preventing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having here:
The external links to the libraries on codepen are not linked to correctly. Or you haven't linked to them at all.

When you click the cog wheel in the JavaSript tab you see external libraries listed there

1. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js`
2. `https://codepen.io/mimikos/pen/GvpJYQ`
3. `https://codepen.io/mimikos/pen/rzOOgG`

**Do you link to these in your code with a `<script>` tag?**

If not, you should do it!

Then, codepen can actually interpret the links to the libraries through context. If you add an external pen with the pen URL in the JS settings, codepen automatically knows that it should be the JS file and imports the appropriate file with the respective filename extensions like listed here: https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/api/url-extensions/

You for yourself have to do this manually. So the HTML you should add to your code is

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://codepen.io/mimikos/pen/GvpJYQ.js"></script>
<script src="https://codepen.io/mimikos/pen/rzOOgG.js"></script>
```

#### But

It is extremely dangerous to link to external code like this. The JS code could change anytime in the future. This could lead to failure and/or (even worse) massive security holes. It's better to download the code and save to your webserver and import these

- Background Noise: https://codepen.io/mimikos/pen/GvpJYQ.js save as js/background-noise.js
- GSAP Old Movie Style: https://codepen.io/mimikos/pen/rzOOgG.js save as js/old-movie-style.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/background-noise.js"></script>
<script src="js/old-movie-style.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep I thought about that and copy pasted the code instead of the urls. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You define a **property** (`white-spacing`), but dont give it a **value** (which it *does expect*):

```
.main-title {
    /* Other properties */
    white-spacing:
}
```

*Also, its not `white-spacing`, but `white-space`*

Comment: Yep that fixed the error, but still not showing exactly how I expected like in the codepen link that I posted above